# Trying to display arraylist in listview gets me this error unable to resolve contructor?

Tags: java, android

I imported an arraylist `mEpisodeList` from another class into my class
to make a horizontal number scrollbar for available episodes , each number representing an episode
I get this [unable to resolve contructor error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbJd1.jpg)  ,

here is the ArrayList [mEpisodeList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYzFw.jpg)

here is the mehtod

```
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import com.miz.loader.TvShowEpisodeLoader;
public class TvShowEpisodeDetailsFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(final View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // populate tvHisPosts layout
        mlistview = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvHisPosts);
        ArrayList<GridEpisode> episodelist = tvShowEpisodeLoader.getEpisodeList();
        // Create The Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, episodelist);
        // Set The Adapter
        mlistview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ArrayAdapter is expecting a string array (`ArrayAdapter<String>`) and your actual ArrayList is of **GridEpisode** type, they do not match. Change this line;

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, episodelist);
```

to this:

```
ArrayAdapter<GridEpisode> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, episodelist);
```

Notice the **ArrayAdapter** type is changed from **String** to **GridEpisode**.

Comment: Thanks , contructor error gone , now I  I'm getting this error https://imgur.com/v8MOENu

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing rest of the code. The error is complaining about some variable called "json".  Probably something going wrong within tvShowEpisodeLoader.getEpisodeList() method or missing getter/setter methods of models that are involved.

Also I have seen Android Studio messing up in debug mode, so if you are sure you don't miss anything, you can try running in release mode to see if this is a real error.

Comment: If you can, you may create a small project that runs and demonstrates just this error (including only required models and methods to run the project) and upload the source code so we can run your code and see what is going on.

Comment: Thanks , the project is very large and recreating just this method need a lot of effort , but I think your right , because at the  `private TvShowEpisodeLoader tvShowEpisodeLoader;`  the `tvShowEpisodeLoader` is grayed , and when I hover the mouse over it it says unassigned

Comment: I also tried release mode , it force closes the app

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through code. This line here

```java
ArrayList<GridEpisode> episodelist = tvShowEpisodeLoader.getEpisodeList();
```

So what we have here an ArrayList of `GridEpisode` data model.

Now coming to your ListView Adapter. This line here

```java
// Create The Adapter
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, episodelist);
```

As you can the Adapter you are trying to create here is of `ArrayAdapter<String>` the `String` class and what you are passing to it is the `episodeList` so that is why it showing you can error since it is expecting a `String` type object.

What you need is a Custom Adapter for your ListView. This [link](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView) will help you through it.

Also I would suggest you to use `RecyclerView` instead. It is much more efficient than `ListView`. Here is a [video reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vyqz_-sJGFk&ab_channel=CodingWithMitch) for the same.

Comment: Thanks , I solved the problem by changing the type of adapter to GridEpisode , I will keep  RecyclerView in mind thanks.